# Access to local resources from tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, desktop, samba

I have got a war deployed in a tomcat. Now I want that any people who connects to our system can access to a samba network. The way that it is done is that each people who access to our system has got in Z: mounted the samba network and when they click over a button, the explorer file must open the route (for example, Z:/Documents). 
I have tried with the Desktop Library (with open and browse) and  with Runtime.getRuntime().exec, without results.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in tomcat context ie the user who started tomcat being it System, Root or tomcat, whichever is your setup. At the same time, your user specific samba mapping depends on the loggedin user. So the actual content of Z:/Documents depends on your operating system user, while your tomcat runs  always as the same user (System, tomcat ...).

The Z:/Documents is a shortcut for a longer network path, for example MyCompay/users/CURENT_USER/Documents (depends how it is configured). 
What you could do is:

- map/mount MyCompany/users folder on your tomcat hosting machine to a path (lets say W:/),
- in your web-app code which fetches the directory, use the username of webapp logged user to resovle the path to right subfolder (its 'home folder') for exmaple W:/user_name/Documents.

But the user, who is used to run the Tomcat, must be able to read all the folders under MyCompay/users